# Is there a IDE that will debug HTML, JavaScript and PHP as one page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ide, dreamweaver

Is there a IDE that will debug HTML/PHP/Javascript on one page, there must be a more efficient way of error finding. Currently I'm using Dreamweaver and if I have a error in my JavaScript or PHP I'm forced to either copy and paste into another environment or read error messages on my testing server.

I've tried Microsoft Visual Studio and it seem like the learning curve is a little steep?! Is Netbeans advisable?

Ideally I would like to carry on using Dreamweaver then if need be just open the page in another IDE, debug, save and reopen in Dreamweaver.

Comment: have you tried phpstorm http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

Comment: No i havent will give it a try, thank you.

Comment: Downvote because?! I hate it when you get a downvote without a reason,  it's not like i'm trying to learn and improve my coding skills. A driveby dote vote benefits no-one!

Comment: Thank you for the reason for downvote! A question better suited for a different forum then i guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/), which can use breakpoints in PHP using X-Debug. It was must-have for me, but now i hardly use the feature since i found the combination of php_error.log + custom log/error outputting easier.

For HTML and Javascript debuggin i simply use Chrome Developer Tools (Rightclick > Inspect, or keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>). The Elements and Console tabs should help you out.

I see no reason to have PHP and JS debug output intertwined, as they never are. There is a linear path here: PHP builds HTML+JS, JS affects HTML, browser renders HTML.

There is also [Embarcadero HTML5 Builder](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/HTML5-Builder) that is said to be highly integrated, i never used it though.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but WebStorm is pretty nice to debug Js. It also help for php and html.

Comment: I will give webstorm a try, thank you.